# Issue with excel cell formatting and formula activation

Tags: excel

I'm having a unique problem that I need some help with.

I have a procedure which pulls data from various sheets into a consolidated worksheet. One piece of data is a date. this is placed into cells within column N which is formatted to DATE *14/03/2012.

In column W I have the below formula and the cells are formatted to General

```
=IF(N14="","",VLOOKUP(N14,W216:X581,2,0))
```

which looks at the date within the cells of column N and then displays a relevant financial year week.

The issue is that when the procedure is run the VLOOKUP doesn't activate until I've double clicked into each cell in column N. Formulas are confirmed as being set to automatic so that's not the issue.
Can anyone suggest a resolution?

Comment: Seems like the cells are formatted as text not sure though, could be one of the reason.

Comment: Calculation mode is manual? Change Application.Calculation from xlCalculationManual to xlCalculationAutomatic